# Defining attribution in OpenLayers3

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers

Can't define options for source attribution. What is the right way to do this?

Tried this two approaches> (My attribution does not change: is open and with default labels )

```
 var tile_photo = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            attributions: [
                new ol.Attribution({
                    html: '<a href="http://link">TEXT</a>',
                    collapsed:true,
                    tipLabel:'My attribution'
                })
            ],
           ...............

        })
});
```

and

```
source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            attributions: [
                new ol.Attribution({
                    html: '<a href="http://link">TEXT</a>',
                    options: {
                        collapsible: true,
                        label: 'A',
                        collapsed: true,
                        tipLabel: 'yooo'
                    }
                })
            ],
.........
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you are using options in the wrong place:

Refering to the [API doc](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.Attribution.html) `ol.Attribution` accepts only `html` as an option.

You have to change the default control for attribution and it's done using an `ol.control.Attribution`. See [the doc](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.control.Attribution.html) about this control.

You should create a new control like below (borrowed from [attribution official sample](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/attributions.html))

```
var attribution = new ol.control.Attribution({
  collapsible: true,
  label: 'A',
  collapsed: true,
  tipLabel: 'yooo'
});
```

and in the map add

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  controls: ol.control.defaults({ attribution: false }).extend([attribution])
});
```

The `ol.control.defaults({ attribution: false }).extend([attribution])` means use default controls except the default attribution (`attribution: false`) and then add the new `attribution` object to list of controls using an array (`.extend([attribution])`)

Comment: I don't know why, but adding new attribution control like that is not working for me. Attribution is added only if I add it after map is created like that `map.addControl(newAttribution);` But I can't remove default attribution.  How can I get to it in form of `map.removeControl(?)` ?

Comment: and if I define `className` to my new attribution control, it dissapears. Do I need to specify this class then somewhere in the sourse, when I define html for attribution?

Comment: Just add `controls: ol.control.defaults({ attribution: false })` and use the `map.addControl(newAttribution);` Is it better?

Comment: I tried `controls: ol.control.defaults({ attribution: false })` but it didn't work for me and I had two attributions on each other.